# When is something considered to be a mathematical proof?

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question

What exactly is a mathetmatical proof? From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079966/can-a-proof-be-just-words/3080030) it's clear it doesn't require any special symbols.

From [a question on another sites](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201992/has-it-been-mathematically-proven-that-antivirus-cant-detect-all-viruses)

> [Computer] Viruses have no “cure.” It’s been mathematically proven that it is
>   always possible to write a virus that any existing antivirus program
>   can’t stop." [0]
>
> [0] Secrets & Lies. Bruce Schneier. Page 154

In these contexts what does it even mean to be mathematically proven? Does it just mean logic was used?

Comment: A *mathematical proof* is so if the community of mathematicians recognise it as such.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA what if the proof is so difficult that only the writer understands it? (which has happened multiple times in history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mathematical proof is a logical argument that proceeds from some assumptions to some conclusions. Symbols are not necessary. In my opinion, good proofs rely on words as much as possible, use symbols only when necessary.

The question you link to

> Has it been mathematically proven that antivirus can't detect all
>   viruses?

has an answer that says the answer is "yes" if you accept a certain precisely stated set of assumptions and define "detect" precisely. Whether those assumptions capture the everyday meaning of "detect a computer virus" isn't a mathematical question.

Related:

[How rigorous must my set theory proof be?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349715/how-rigorous-must-my-set-theory-proof-be/2349722#2349722)

[Why is there not a system for computer checking mathematical proofs yet (2018)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2747661/why-is-there-not-a-system-for-computer-checking-mathematical-proofs-yet-2018/2747708#2747708)

Comment: Thanks, I was going to delete my question but your answer provides interesting information